# What's with the IF in this query

Tags: sql

This is my query

```
update b
set b.col1 =   if(1) <= 0
             begin
              select 1 as bal
                end
             else 
              select 0 as bal

from 
dbo.table1 b
inner join  dbo.table1 a
on b.id = a.id
and b.date = a.date
```

The "IF" part works great by itself. Puting it in this query form throws

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'.

am I missing something other than sleep.

Comment: Why is my query not showing up?????

Comment: Fixed it for ya - got rid of the pre and code tags and used the edit buttons instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a CASE WHEN statement within queries

```
update b
set b.col1 = CASE WHEN 1 <= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 1):

"if" is a statement, so you can't use it as an expression. You can use "case" instead:

```
update b
set b.col1 = case when 1 <= 0 then 1 else 0 end
from  dbo.table1 b
inner join dbo.table1 a on b.id = a.id and b.date = a.date
```

(The expression in your if doesn't make much sense though, as the condition always has the same value.)

Answer (score 0):

how about using

```
set b.col1 = case when if(1) <=0 then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: This is just a test query. The original is quite complex and was trying the "IF". I'll look at the CASE instead

Answer (score 0):

Yeah.

In some SQL dialects there's an `if` that's a function. if(expresion1,expresion2,expresion3)

In some SQL dialects, there's an `if ...then .. endif` that's a flow-of-control construct.

Some SQL dialects have both.

That later form can generally be used only in a store procedure/function; the former wherever a function can be used.